# adding a grid layout panel and a border layout panel to a frame in java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I was wondering how I could position my panels to be in the same jframe with my grid layout panel in the center and my border layout at the bottom. Like This: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUE47.jpg But it was tricky because i don't know how to position panels in a jframe. Here is my code:

```
public GameWindow()

{
    super("Game Window");
    this.setSize(1500, 800);
    this.setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    label1 = new JLabel("");
    label2 = new JLabel("");
    label3 = new JLabel("");
    label4 = new JLabel("");
    label5 = new JLabel("");

    int i = 15;
    int j = 20;
    JPanel[][] panel1 = new JPanel[i][j];
    setLayout(new GridLayout(i,j));

    for(int m = 0; m < i; m++) {
       for(int n = 0; n < j; n++) {
          panel1[m][n] = new JPanel();
          this.add(panel1[m][n]);
       }
    }

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), 100));
    panel2.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    this.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("status");
    statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    panel2.add(statusLabel);

    this.setVisible(true);

    down = new JButton("down");
    right = new JButton("right");
    left= new JButton("left");
    up = new JButton("up");
    fight = new JButton("fight");
    flee = new JButton("flee");

    panel1[5][3].add(up);
    panel1[8][4].add(left);
    panel1[7][2].add(right);
    panel1[3][5].add(down);
    panel2.add(label1);
    panel2.add(label2);
    panel2.add(label3);
    panel2.add(label4);
    panel2.add(label5);
    panel2.add(fight);
    panel2.add(flee);
```

When I run it, it shows up like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUYqt.png
I want the status bar to be across the whole bottom but it doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: sorry for my question, but why you have all of those panels? I think I should be enough for the upper part of your layout

Comment: I only have 2 panels, 1 for the top and 1 for the bottom. I want the grid layout on top, and the status bar on the bottom.

Comment: I see you are creating a matrix of `JPanel` with this line `JPanel[][] panel1 = new JPanel[i][j];`, and I don't understand why if you need only a single jPanel on top :)